# Prove this inequality $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2(a+b+c)^3\ge 27(ab+bc+ac)^2$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, substitution, uvw

**Question:**

> let $a,b,c>0$ show that
> $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2(a+b+c)^3\ge 27(ab+bc+ac)^2$$

since
$$(a+b+c)^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ac)\Longleftrightarrow (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge 0$$

it is enough to show that
$$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2(a+b+c)\ge 9(ab+bc+ac)$$
Following it hard to prove.maybe this inequality can use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last inequality is wrong. Try $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $a=b=1$.

But your starting inequality is true.

We need to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geq27(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)^2$$
for positives $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$u^2(3u^2-2v^2)^3\geq(3v^4-2uw^3)^2$$ or
$$u\sqrt{(3u^2-2v^2)^3}-3v^4+2uw^3\geq0.$$
Thus, it remains to prove our inequality for a minimal value of $w^3$.

Now, we know that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive roots of the equation
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=0$$ or
$$x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x-w^3=0$$ or
$$w^3=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x,$$
which says that a line $y=w^3$ and the graph of $y=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x$ have three common points
and $w^3$ gets a minimal value, when the line $y=w^3$ is a tangent line to the graph of $y=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Also we must check the case $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $b=1$.

We have here $(a+1)^2(a^2+1)^3\geq27a^4$, which is AM-GM:
$$(a+1)^2(a^2+1)^3\geq\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)^2(2a)^3=32a^4\geq27a^4;$$

2. $b=c=1$, which gives
   $$(a-1)^2(a^6+6a^5+21a^4+60a^3+27a^2+42a+5)\geq0.$$
   Done!

Also we can make the following.

We need to prove that
$$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)^3\geq27(ab+ac+bc)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$
Now, by Holder 
$$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(a+b+c)^3.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^6\geq27(ab+ac+bc)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2),$$
which is AM-GM:
$$(a+b+c)^6=(a^2+b^2+c^2+(ab+ac+bc)+(ab+ac+bc))^3\geq$$
$$\geq\left(3\sqrt[3]{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+ac+bc)^2}\right)^3=27(ab+ac+bc)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$
Done!

Comment: @Macavity Thank you, but I think the first proof we can see immediately.

Comment: The first method is very useful, however I think many people are not familiar with it, so they would be more satisfied with the proof using holder's inequality. And I believe for marketing purposes this answer would have gotten more upvotes if the holder proof was first.

Comment: @clark Thank you! By my opinion the first way is much better than second.